delete the characters of a filename from a specific position
i have 100 files in a folder with filenames as below
Example1: GCA_000696115.1_SoWt_assembly_genomic.fna 
          (0 to 15 characters are GCA_000696115.1)

Question1: remove characters after 15th character
          (i.e from, _SoWt_assembly_genomic.fna)

Example 2 : GCA_123456789.1xx_NgalHAMBI1146Draft_genomic.fna 
            (0 to 17 characters are GCA_123456789.1xx) 

Question2 : remove characters after 17th character
          (i.e from, _NgalHAMBI1146Draft_genomic.fna) 


in above examples i want to remove characters 
of the filename (after/from specific positions:
(15, 17 th positions) of the files in a folder 


Thank you in advance

For the given example, can you please add your expected output?

If you remove one of the colons, i.e. "${file:15}", you get _SoWt_assembly_genomic.fna, _NgalHAMBI1146Draft_genomic.fna, and _ASM399070v1_genomic.fna. Note that your script also appends .txt to them. (Use :14 if you want these files to start with 1_)

If you mean keep characters from position 15 to the end try echo ${file#*.[0-9]_} which finds and removes GCA_000696115.1_ SoWt_assembly_genomic.fna  and prints SoWt_assembly_genomic.fna, hence would work for dynamic locations.

please see my edits

What's wrong with what you have then? Seems to be working for me.

the code works for me; please update the question to explain what your code is doing wrong

the code work to extract/rename first 15 or 17 characters or required characters. I request the code to be modified so that it removes/delete the characters after specific positions of the string (i.e., after 15or 17 or any position) - please see my edits - thank you

why did you remove your coding attempt? how do you know beforehand if it's going to be 15 or 17 characters, or would a more accurate description be that you want to keep everything up to the 2nd underscore (_)?

@markp-fuso the first 15 characters of the filename are constant i.e, the number of characters after 2nd underscore () differ. In case if one want to remove from 2nd underscore, i think "($f%*).txt" should work. The second id with 17 characters is given as example.  To understand, the main goal is to remove characters after specific position (15 or 17  characters after, irrespective of special characters) .

Your question is unclear: Are the names of the files stored in a file, or in a bash variable (for instance a bash array)? Also, why is the question tagged rename. There is no renaming mentioned in the question.

https://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/ https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

I just can refer to what I understood or failed to understand. For instance, to translate a filename in this way, I would do it differently if the name is stored in an array or in a textfile, and if I need the translation for the purpose of  actually renaming a file, I would approach it in yet a different way. You only describe that you want extract a substring of a filename, without saying, what you are then going to do with that substring, or how you get the filename. Since all this is unclear, you got 3 already 3 different answers, which all have different assumption on your problem.

@user1934428 please see my edits i have 100 files with filenames in a folder, so i want to remove the characters after/from 15 or 17 positions (which may be constant)
file in *; do mv "$file" "${file:15}.out"; done - cut first 15 characters. But i want to keep first 15 characters and delete after 15 or 17 characters/ specific position(s)- (similar to, for example drop columns from 6 to 10, thus keeping 0-5 columns in pandas dataframe) - hope i am clear now please let me know - thank you

I don't understand the or in 15 or 17. Is this a parameter, i.e. on some days you want to remove 15 characters and on some days 17? In this case, the suggestions by user Linux or Diego Torres Milano look promising. If they answer your question, don't forget to accept one of them.

@user1934428 ok then please consider ONE file with filename (15 characters) - ok thank you for your suggestion to look into Linux or Diego Torres Mialno. The positions might be (15 or 17), but they have same meaning "$file" "${file:15}.out"; or "$file" "${file:17}.out"; is it right ?.

Sure. Doing the truncation on the parameter instead of creating a child process for cut is better.  Also, depending on your use case, consider using mv -v instead of mv. BTW, I wind the rename solution by Diego more elegant, but you need to check whether you have this tool. Yet another approach would be to switch from bash to zsh, which comes with a command zmv, which is extremely convenient to use.

@ all : Thank you very much for your codes

Using rename (which you can install for your distro if you don't have it already), you can do
rename -v -n -e 's/(^.{15}).*/$1.txt/' GCA*

remove the -n to actually do the renaming.

can you please elaborate the code $1.txt /' GCA*

$1 argument 1 - got it now thank you Diego

$1 is the first capture group (perl re), whatever is captured for the ( )

Run in your terminal:
for file in yourfoldername/*; do mv "$file" "$(echo $file | cut -c1-15).txt"; done


can you please let me know file in *; do mv "$file" "${file:15}.out"; done - works same as the code you provided - Thank you

Assumptions:

OP hasn't described how the number of characters (eg, 15 or 17) is determined so based on OP's sample file names I'm going to guess ...
we want to keep everything up to, but not including, the 2nd underscore (_) and then ...
append .txt on the end
if a file name has less than 2 underscores we'll flag it as an invalid file name (OP can update the code to handle this scenario as they see fit)

Putting together a list of sample file names from OP's various edits plus a few more of my own:
$ ls -1
GCA_000696115.1_SoWt_assembly_genomic.fna
GCA_000985875.1_NgalHAMBI1146Draft_genomic.fna
GCA_003990705.1_ASM399070v1_genomic.fna
GCA_123456789.1xx_NgalHAMBI1146Draft_genomic.fna
GCA_123-456.789_some_other_stuff.fna
GCA_abc_defghijkl.789_some_other_stuff.fna
GCA-invalid-file-name.fna                           # no underscores
GCA_invalid-file-name.fna                           # only one underscore

One bash idea using read to parse the file name based on the underscore (_) as delimiter:
for old_fname in *.fna
do
    [[ ! -f "${old_fname}" ]] && break                       # address scenario  where there are no matches on  *.fna

    IFS='_' read -r part1 part2 rest <<< "${old_fname}"      # split file name on underscore delimiter

    if [[ -z "${rest}" ]]                                    # if we have less than 2 underscores then ...
    then
        new_fname='***** INVALID FILE NAME *****'            # flag as invalid else ...
    else
        new_fname="${part1}_${part2}.txt"                    # create the new file name
    fi 

    printf "old: %s\nnew: %s\n\n" "${old_fname}" "${new_fname}"
done

This generates:
old: GCA_000696115.1_SoWt_assembly_genomic.fna
new: GCA_000696115.1.txt

old: GCA_000985875.1_NgalHAMBI1146Draft_genomic.fna
new: GCA_000985875.1.txt

old: GCA_003990705.1_ASM399070v1_genomic.fna
new: GCA_003990705.1.txt

old: GCA_123456789.1xx_NgalHAMBI1146Draft_genomic.fna
new: GCA_123456789.1xx.txt

old: GCA_123-456.789_some_other_stuff.fna
new: GCA_123-456.789.txt

old: GCA_abc_defghijkl.789_some_other_stuff.fna
new: GCA_abc.txt

old: GCA-invalid-file-name.fna
new: ***** INVALID FILE NAME *****

old: GCA_invalid-file-name.fna
new: ***** INVALID FILE NAME *****

